# asp.net user control element is null

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple asp.net user control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeBehind="QueryDefinitionItem.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="xxx.UserControls.QueryDefinitionItem" %>
    <link href="../Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <div class="title">
      <h1 id="TextField" runat="server"></h1>
    </div>
```

Code behind:

```
 public partial class QueryDefinitionItem : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    private string m_text;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextField.InnerText = m_text;
    }

    public void SetText(string text)
    {
        m_text = text;
    }
}
```

I use LoadControl to load one instance programatically:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var control = (QueryDefinitionItem)LoadControl(typeof (QueryDefinitionItem),null);
        control.SetText("test2");
        itemsPanel.Controls.Add(control);}
```

I then use the SetText function to set the text and once the Page Load is fired I get a NullReferenceException that says TextField is null...

I cant figure out why.

Comment: At what point are you adding the control dynamically ?

Comment: @RichardFriend Its the page load event of the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have to use [LoadControl(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.templatecontrol.loadcontrol.aspx)  method instead of `LoadControl(Type,Param)` and store value directly to the HtmlControl. (There is bug take a look at [connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/103456/usercontrol-loaded-by-loadcontrol-type-object-does-not-create-its-children)).

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
public void SetText(string text)
{
  TextField.InnerText = text;
}
```

Or create a property,

```
   public string Text
    {
      get { return TextField.InnerText; }
      set { TextField.InnerText=value;  }
    }
```

Use `Page_Init` or `Page_Load` event to create controls dynamically.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
  var control = (QueryDefinitionItem)LoadControl("~/QueryDefinitionItem.ascx");
  control.SetText("test2");
  itemsPanel.Controls.Add(control);
  }
```

Comment: @Amit Where are you trying to access that TextField. I mean in which event it is returning you null. Is it Page_Load of control or the page where you are creating it?

Comment: @AVD I am creating the user control at the page load event of the page and I have tried to access it on the page load of the control. I have also tried accesing it (user the method you offered) directly from the page load of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the same code but in page pre render should work.

Answer (score 0):

Swap these around

```
control.SetText("test2");   
itemsPanel.Controls.Add(control);
```

Becomes

```
itemsPanel.Controls.Add(control);
control.SetText("test2");
```

Your user control will not have created its control tree until it is added to the control tree itself.

You can also use [EnsureChildControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.ensurechildcontrols.aspx) to make sure it has created its controls.

```
public void SetText(string text)  { 
    EnsureChildControls();
    TextField.InnerText = text;  
}
```

I would also recommend creating your control before page_load, [this is a good read](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Dynamically_Created_Controls_in_ASPNET.aspx)